# How to increase the query time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Is there any possibility of increasing the query execution time out time in the program using C#.NET, Windows Forms?

In my program I am executing a query in a loop. On the first two iterations the query executes in 10 sec each time. On the third iteration it takes around 40-50 sec for the query to complete and now I am not able to extract data from that query, because a time out exception is raised and the execution flow goes to the `catch` block where the corresponding error message is displayed.

Is there any possibility of executing queries which take more than 30 sec using C#.NET in Windows application?

Below is my code:

```
try
{
    tab = "dbo.basic_sp_mst";
    error1 = "" + site + "." + orgname + "";
    ls = "" + site + "." + site + "." + tab + "";
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + ls + " where (last_updated_date between(getdate()-3) and (getdate()-1)) order by last_updated_date,bsp_item_cd", con);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    da2.Fill(dt5);
    dt6 = dt5;

    SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter("select a. bsp_item_cd ,a.bsp_mrp,a.last_updated_date,b.bsp_item_cd ,b.bsp_mrp,b.last_updated_date,c.name from basic_sp_mst a," + ls + " b,sys.servers c where  a.bsp_item_cd =  b.bsp_item_cd and a.bsp_mrp<> b.bsp_mrp and a.bsp_org_cd=" + s + " and c.name<>'001' and c.name='" + site + "'", con);......................(this is the main query) if this query is taking more than 30sec it is going to catch block.......

    DataSet dss = new DataSet();
    daa.Fill(dt7);
    dt8 = dt7;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    msg2 = " query time out error at store id:" + error1 + "";
    dataGridView8.Rows.Add(msg2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just increase CommandTimeout property of the SqlDataAdapter.

```
// Set timeout to 2 minutes
daa.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=120;
```

This command goes after the `new SqlDataAdapter` definition and before the call to `Fill`.

Also, check if the table have indexes on the columns on your `Where` section of the `Select` command, to try to reduce the query time.

You also can [use the MS SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650692.aspx) to receive recommendation on indexes that could improve the performance.